# PHP via Amazon S3 for Android App

Tags: php, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have developed an Android app which does a GET/PUT operations with a test web server for fetching and storing data in JSON format. For PUT using a PHP script on webserver via parameters in url. Now to scale the solution, i am exploring AWS solutions. How to achieve PHP script based logic handling on webserver with AWS S3 or any other cloud based storage which can perform this php based logic handling.

Comment: you are kind of not clear, but if I got you correct, AWS has their own APIs for all of this so you don't need to create your PHP you can just use their APIs.

Comment: but i have my own PHP script which does data handling on server and want a solution which can be deployed with my app. too much of rework can lead to lot of delays.

Comment: Then just put your script to a normal server on AWS nginx, or apache they are available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use AWS Lambda- It doesn't need servers to be hosted and maintained, which is a big headache. With AWS Lambda, in few minutes you can get your web application running. Your PHP scripts can be hosted as service and AWS will take care of its scalability and availability.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOBq__h4OJ4 
https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/build-a-web-app/
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scripting-languages-for-aws-lambda-running-php-ruby-and-go/

AWS S3 you can use for storing your static files like images, css, javascript etc...

Comment: Do you mean, S3 for storing JSON data files, images and AWS Lambda working over top of it which will make use of my PHP scripts ? So, when my android application does a put request it will go to lambda and it will take care of storage operation post processing on S3. Is this understanding correct ?

Comment: Yes, every object placed in S3 will have an http URL using which you can access them in your script.